# Why can't I prime factor numbers above a certain magnitude?

Tags: c++, int, prime-factoring, long-double, large-data

I'm trying to write a program in C++ that will prime factor numbers that have 12 digits. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  long double userInput;
  long double divisor = 2;
  long double dividend;

  cout << "Enter number:   ";
  cin >> userInput;
  dividend = userInput;

  do
  {
    while (static_cast<int>(dividend) % static_cast<int>(divisor) == 0)
    {
      cout << divisor << endl;
      dividend = dividend / divisor;
    }

    divisor++;

  } while (dividend > 1);

  return 0;
}
```

This (seems to, at least) works fine for smaller numbers, but it breaks down when I use really high numbers. Why is this? Do I need to use a larger integer type? Or is it something wrong with the code itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `long double` for factorization doesn't make much sense.  You want a large integer type to represent whole numbers. `double` is typically 64 bits, but it "wastes" several of those bits for the exponent so it can represent fractional numbers, and also numbers with a very large magnitude but reduced precision.

Also, you convert the dividend and divisor to `int` before dividing them. `int` is very often 32 bits, which means any number over about 2 billion (10 digits) will overflow, giving meaningless results. It *can* be as narrow as 16 bits, which gives it a range of just -32768 to +32767; you usually shouldn't assume that it's necessarily wider than that.

If your compiler supports it (and it probably does), use type `long long`, which is at least 64 bits.  That's nearly 19 decimal digits, which is more than enough for your requirements.

Comment: Further, `int` can be as small as 16 bits, so -65,536 through 65,535 (in a twos-complement representation).

Comment: @PeteBecker: Updated. (BTW, it's -32768 .. +32767.)

Comment: I don't suppose you'd believe that I **really** meant a 17-bit `int`?

Comment: @PeteBecker: Are you sure you *want* me to believe that?

Comment: Well, there are 17 bit computers.... http://www.academia.edu/7676395/Novel_Architecture_of_17_Bit_Address_RISC_CPU_with_Pipelining_Technique_Using_Xilinx_in_VLSI_Technology